# Как сделать гиперссылку в сообщении?

Tags: c#

Пишу телеграмм бота на C# и столкнулся с такой проблемой создании гиперссылки в сообщении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант в InlineKeyBoard добавить ссылку.

```
        var hyperLinkKeyboard = new Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.InlineKeyboardMarkup(Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.InlineKeyboardButton.WithUrl("Нажми меня для перехода на ссылку", "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/"));
        await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat, "Текст", replyMarkup: hyperLinkKeyboard);
```